# must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial c#

Tags: c#, declare

Any ideas on why I am getting this error? I know it may be a simple fix but I'm completely new to C# and I'm unable to find any fixes around.

'SimpleMath.UI.Add_operation.btnCalculate_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;


namespace SimpleMath.UI
{
    class Add_operation
    {
        public string Calculate(decimal i, decimal j)
        {
            return (i + j).ToString();
        }
        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well - have you tried declaring a body (`{}`) for `btnCalculate_Click`?

Comment: Why would you not want to declare a body for btnCalculate_Click? Its a method afterall ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114(v=vs.80).aspx )

Comment: Perhaps also explain what you are trying to achieve with it having no body, if that is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a **body** in your `btnCalculate_Click` method:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

namespace SimpleMath.UI
{
    class Add_operation
    {
        public string Calculate(decimal i, decimal j)
        {
            return (i + j).ToString();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // do some stuff here
           // or remove the method if it's empty
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is crystal clear. Your method btnCalculate_Click doesn't have a body!